# FindControl in a RoleGroup in a LoginView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't seem to find a control in a login view.

The aspx is:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="SuperUserLV" runat="server">
    <RoleGroups>
            <asp:RoleGroup Roles="SuperUser">
                    <ContentTemplate>       
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="Active" runat="server" /><br />
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="RequireValidaton" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

And the code behind is:

```
if (Context.User.IsInRole("SuperUser"))
{
    CheckBox active = (CheckBox) SuperUserLV.FindControl("Active");
    if (active != null)
    {
        active.Checked = this.databaseObject.Active;
    }

    CheckBox require = (CheckBox) SuperUserLV.FindControl("RequireValidaton");
    if (require != null)
    {
        require.Checked = this.databaseObject.RequiresValidation;
    }
}
```

With a user in the right role, I can see the checkboxes, but the code behind doesn't populate them, the result of the findcontrol is null.

What am I missing? Thanks.

**Edit**: Looks like my issue was when I am doing the `.FindControl` the loginview hasn't rendered to the screen and is returning null. Putting my code on a button and calling it after the page has rendered to the screen it works as I would expect.

**Edit 2**: Seems the best place to put the code was `SuperUserLV_ViewChanged`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in FindControl method only searches the direct child controls. You'll need to write a recursive version of the method to search all descendants. Following is an untested example that likely needs some optimization:

```
public Control RecursiveFindControl(Control parent, string idToFind)
{
    for each (Control child in parent.ChildControls)
    {
        if (child.ID == idToFind)
        {
            return child;
        }
        else
        {
            Control control = RecursiveFindControl(child, idToFind);
            if (control != null)
            {
                return control;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: There's no ChildControls collection on the login view, there is a controls collection but it contains nothing.