# Change label text on master page from the Master page's Code Behind (vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I am creating a badge notification in a navigation list item. I would like to be able to update the label from the code behind of the master page. I am stuck here is my code.

```
<asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                        <%--<li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>--%>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Submissions<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                <li><a runat="server" href="Submissions">Submissions</a></li>
                                                <li><a runat="server" href="SubmissionEmails">Emails</a></li>
                                                <li><a runat="server" href="SubmissionEmailTemplate">Email Template</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a runat="server" href="Faults">Faults</a></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Reporting<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                <li><a runat="server" href="CompanyDeclaration">Declaration</a></li>
                                                <li><a runat="server" href="CompanyDeclarationSummary">Summary</a></li>
                                                <li><a runat="server" href="CompanyTemplate">Template</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><img src="/images/person.png"> <%: Context.User.Identity.Name()%> <label class="badge badge-danger" ID="Count" runat="server">5</label><span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Admin/FaultCodeRules">Fault Code Rules</a></li>
                                                <li><a <a runat="server" href="~/Admin/Smelters">Standard Smelters</a></li>
                                                <%--<li><a href="#">Back Flush</a></li>--%>
                                                <%--<li><a runat="server" href="SalesData">Sales Data</a></li>--%>
                                                <%--<li><a runat="server" href="Vendor">Vendor</a></li>--%>
                                                <%--<li><a runat="server" href="Usage">WebSite Usage</a></li>--%>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li class="dropdown-header">Admin Tools</li>
                                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Admin/PendingRegistrations">Pending Registrations <label class="badge badge-danger" ID="UCount" runat="server">13</label></a></li>
                                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Admin/AssignRoles">Assign Roles</a></li>
                                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Admin/AddFactory">Add New Factory</a></li>
                                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Admin/Register">Register User</a></li>
                                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Admin/SwitchUser">View as another Factory</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Manage Your Account</a></li>                                              
                                                <li>
                                                   <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                               </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a runat="server" href="Default"><img alt="Home" src="/images/Home-24.png"></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:RoleGroup>
```

> ```
>  Snippet
> ```

```
<li><a runat="server" href="~/Admin/PendingRegistrations">Pending Registrations <asp:Label class="badge badge-danger" ID="Label1" runat="server" /></a></li>
```

Here is the code in my code behind file.

```
Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString
Dim con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = con
con.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "Select Count(*) From User_Register"
Dim UserCount = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
con.Close()
label1.text = UserCount
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
Dim lv As LoginView = DirectCast(FindControl("myLoginView"), LoginView)
                Dim ln As Label = DirectCast(lv.FindControl("Count"), Label)
                ln.Text = UserCount.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

Your LoginView is a templated control and as such, the controls cannot be accessed as you're trying.  `FindControl` normally works, but in this case, only searches direct child controls.

So you might do something like this (replacing `MyLoginViewID` with your LoginView's ID:

```
Dim label as Label = CType(FindControlRecursive(MyLoginViewID, "Label1"), Label)
label.Text = UserCount.ToString()
```

Below is a method I've used before, and my answer was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372158/findcontrol-in-a-rolegroup-in-a-loginview)

```
''' <summary>
    ''' Recursively loops through all containers in a control looking for the specified control.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="callingControl"></param>
    ''' <param name="controlId"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function FindControlRecursive(ByVal callingControl As System.Web.UI.Control, ByVal controlId As String) As System.Web.UI.Control

        If callingControl Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

        Dim ctrl As Control = callingControl.FindControl(controlId)

        If ctrl Is Nothing Then
            For Each child As Control In callingControl.Controls
                ctrl = FindControlRecursive(child, controlId)
                If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then Exit For
            Next
        End If

        Return ctrl

    End Function
```

Comment: Im using the code behind in the master page only. I dont want to put the code on every single page.

Comment: Sorry.. I misread the question, but will update when I understand the issue.  What doesn't work when you use `Label1.Text = UserCount` as you've shown then?

Comment: I have the blue line under label1. It does not recognize label1.text.  The Master page code behind does not recognize any id's from the master page.

Comment: Is Label1 inside of a `Repeater` or a `Datalist` control? (Or some other templated control which typically would not allow you to address it directly?)

Comment: Its inside a <li> its part of my navigation. I'm trying to create a badge with a count from the database.

Comment: I re-edited.  Please try the new example and see if it helps.

Comment: I get an error                                                                                                          Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: This page is in c# but it gives a good explaination of how FindControl works in a LoginView  http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/find-control-with-in-loginview-control

Comment: Thanks @InbetweenWeekends  Your answer helped me find a solution.